# Get Frame from CGPath

Tags: ios, cgpath, cashapelayer

I am working with `CGPath` and `CAShapeLayer`. I have drawn non linear path. So how to find `frame` from `CGPath` which should be exactly taken space by `CGPath`? Because I am drawing so many `CGPath` which are nearer to other `CGPath`'s. Yes I know about `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path)`, but it is giving me rectangle frame so it is over lapping to other `CAShapeLayer`.

Any pointers?